# Me sale este error cuando quiero actualizar una tabla php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy trabado con un código que me sale un error al ejecutar la sentencia no se si me pueden ayudar...

Este es el php

```html
  if($_POST)  {

     
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];

      $sql_agregar = 'UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = pablo, apellidos = ramos WHERE usuarios.id = 7';
      $sentencia_agregar = $pdo->prepare($sql_agregar);
      $sentencia_agregar->execute(array($nombre,$apellidos));
 
  
      header('location:index.php'); // Esto redirige la acción a la página actual
  }

  if($_GET) {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $sql_unico = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=7';
      $gsent_unico = $pdo->prepare($sql_unico);
      $gsent_unico->execute(array($id));
      $resultado_unico = $gsent_unico->fetch();   
  }
```

Dentro de este php tengp un formulario para actualizar los datos de contacto del perfil que ha ingresado con su contraseña.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4"><?php  ?></h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-start mt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-control">
                <h3>Cambiar información de contacto</h3>
            <form method="POST" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
                <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php ?>">
                <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Y cuando actualizo los datos del perfil me indica este error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCurso\phpyMySQL\form-sesion\profile.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCurso\phpyMySQL\form-sesion\profile.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCurso\phpyMySQL\form-sesion\profile.php on line 25`

Este seria el archivo conexion.php donde esta guardada la variable $pdo.

```html
<?php

$link = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=coloresphp';
$usuario = 'root'; 
$pass = '';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($link, $usuario, $pass);
    //  echo '<br><br>Conectado';

  

    // foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `colores`') as $fila) {
    //     print_r($fila);
    // }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

No se si me pueden ayudar, porque llevo varias horas trabado en lo mismo.

Comment: Deberías poner marcadores en tu consulta para poder pasar los datos con  `execute()`, por ejemplo: `UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = ?, apellidos = ? WHERE id = 7`. No sé por qué el `id` lo tienes fijo en `7`, supongo que deberás recoger un ID dinámico como haces con el nombre y el apellido.

Comment: @A.Cedano de momento lo tengo así para probar la actualización de la tabla con lo secuencia de SQL, ya luego lo dejo dinamico

Comment: Entiendo, pero si usas una consulta preparada ésta debe tener marcadores, no datos directos, pues cuando pasas datos en el  `execute` PDO verificará en la instrucción SQL a qué marcadores pertenecen esos datos y no está encontrando marcadores, ése es el motivo del error.

Comment: Ahh ok, creo que lo he entendido @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
> number of tokens

ocurre cuando la cantidad de marcadores y de parámetros no coinciden en una consulta preparada.

En el código estás pasando dos datos en el `execute()`, pero no hay marcadores para esos datos en el `UPDATE`.

Debes corregirlo poniendo marcadores de posición:

```
  $sql_agregar = 'UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = ?, apellidos = ? WHERE id = 7';
  $sentencia_agregar = $pdo->prepare($sql_agregar);
  $sentencia_agregar->execute(array($nombre,$apellidos));
```

O marcadores de nombre, en cuyo caso los nombres deben ir también en el array:

```
  $sql_agregar = 'UPDATE usuarios SET nombre =:nombre, apellidos =:apellidos WHERE id = 7';
  $sentencia_agregar = $pdo->prepare($sql_agregar);
  $sentencia_agregar->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre,':apellidos'=>$apellidos));
```

Comment: Tu respuesta funciona correctamente, por un pequeño fallo casi lo tenia muchas gracias :)